# Оставить в массиве k различных чисел

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

В университете дали задание, не могу придумать как решить:
Дан массив *длины n*, нам при помощи двух действий **(прибавление к наименьшему элементу массива единицы или вычитание из наибольшего элемента 1)** надо сделать так, чтобы в массиве после всех действий *осталось k различных чисел*.
То есть, из массива **-1; -5; 7; 8; 2; 1; 10**, надо получить **-1; -1; 7; 7; 7; 2; 1.**
Может кто встречался с подобным, а то из идей была только сортировка, но я не понимаю, что делать с этим дальше...

Comment: [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1518182/edit) в метках язык программирования. Если язык не важен, то укажите метку `любой-язык`. Пробовали ли решать эту задачу самостоятельно? Распишите подробнее в самом вопросе, с чем конкретно у вас возникла трудность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо, отсортировали по возрастанию.

Теперь используем метод двух указателей.

Левый индекс поставим на `0`, правый тоже, и начнём двигать правый, пока в окне между двух указателей от `L` до `R-1` не будет ровно `k` различных элементов.

Теперь посчитаем сумму значений справа `RSum`, и сколько нужно от значений справа отнять единиц, чтобы все правые элементы стали как `R-1`-ый, это начальное значение для

```
MinOnes = RSum - A[R-1]*(n-R)
```

Начинаем двигать левый указатель, пока количество различных элементов в окне не станет меньше `k`, при этом считая сумму, оставшуюся слева `LSum`.

Продолжим двигать правый, как и раньшe, уменьшая `RSum`. При остановке правого посчитаем необходимое количество единиц и сравним с `MinOnes`

```
Ones = (RSum - A[R-1]*(n-R)) + ((A[L]*(L-1) - LSum))
```

Повторяем продвижение окна, содержащего ровно `k` различных элементов, до конца.

Comment: Привет, земляк! Спасибо большое за помощь, у меня есть два вопроса: зачем после сдвига [R] нам надо сравнивать его с [MinOnes], и что означает идти до конца (всё равно в конце RSum будет равен 0), когда будет получен ответ и что это будет за переменная?

Comment: Сравнивать нужно не R, а количество единиц при текущем R c лучшим количеством единиц. Таким образом, после продвижения по массиву окна, всегда содержащего k значений, выберем лучший результат. В самом конце весь вклад будет от левой части

Comment: То есть после подсчёта мы двигаем не отдельно 'L' или 'R', а весь отрезок длины 'K'. Но возникает проблема, в том что MinOnes после первого подсчёта отрицательный, и тогда в сравнении нет смысла...

Comment: Внёс уточнение - у меня был разнобой в первой и второй формулах

Comment: Нет, длина отрезка меняется,  а вот количество разных элементов сохраняется